# Access Form Vba Update Record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to update a record in Microsoft Access database using forms but is giving and error Expected en of statement. :|

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Ensamblador]" _
"SET NumerodeEnsamblador=" & Me.textboxone  & "" _
", NombredeEnsamblador='" & Me.textboxtwo & "'" & _
", Especialidad='" & Me.textboxthree & "'" & _
" WHERE NumerodeEnsamblador=" & Me.textboxone
```

Comment: try adding a space in front of `SET` - and you first value has no leading and trailing `'`. And your are failing to escape your input, if a user inputs `test'test` your query will always fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably read:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Ensamblador " & _
"SET NombredeEnsamblador = '" & Me.textboxtwo & "'" & _
", Especialidad='" & Me.textboxthree & "' " & _
"WHERE NumerodeEnsamblador=" & Me.textboxone & ""
```